# Move Windows 7 to SSD without reinstalling and too small SSD

Tags: windows, partitioning, ssd

today I got a SSD and I wanted to move my windows 7 to it, but would have to copy 800GB from my HDD to my SSD which has 120GB. The problem is that it is not possible to copy winodws only to the SSD and I dont want to reinstall/download around 800GB, as this would take ages with my internet. My question is, is it possible to install windows on the SSD and then link the paths of the windows on my HDD to the windows of my SSD? Then I dont have to reinstall everything, is this possible and if yes, is it useful or only complicated?

Comment: Can both drives be fitted? Is it a desktop or laptop? What folders host the majority of the 800gb?

Comment: If you install windows from scratch on the SSD, you lose all your applications. You can't reinstall them by linking folders. A simpler (and costlier) solution is to get a 1TB SSD.

Comment: As I can't make a comment I will have to write an answer, 500GB is taken by my Program Files (x86) folder and it is a desktop. What do you mean with "Can both drives be fitted?"

Comment: First of all, welcome to Super User! We are always glad to help, but you apparently have **three** Super User accounts: [this one](https://superuser.com/users/963800/error666), [this one](https://superuser.com/users/963805/error666), and [this one](https://superuser.com/users/963806/error666). Please take the time to utilize the following Help Center tutorial and ask the Super User staff to merge your accounts: [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: Cramming 500GB of programs in 120GB is really impossible. The small SSD is enough for the OS and many programs but not that much. Most you'll be able to install in a different drive but no, you can't reuse the previous installation.

Comment: 500Gb in Program Files? That’s really excessive. It’s highly unlikely that data is programs. Have you checked to see what is actually consuming that space in Program Files?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following way:

Check how big the C drive is on the Windows 7 operating system on hdd.

The size of the SSD must be greater than the size of the C drive on hdd.

If so, clone the C drive on hdd to ssd via the ghost tool.

After the clone is completed, the machine will restart.

When restarting, check whether the startup item of the operating system has ssd.

If not, first set ssd as the priority startup item in BIOS.

If it still cannot be started from ssd, log in to hdd's operating system and use the tool to fix the boot menu.

After the boot menu is fixed, check if the boot entry of the operating system has ssd, if so and then we start it from ssd.

Comment: Do you mean Symantec Ghost? This is only trialware, as far as I know, is there a reason not to use one of the free software versions available?